# Is it possible to reset an entire class without looping through the elements

Tags: css, class, reset

I have a 12 month calendar. When a user clicks on the month I am calling my function toggleZoom
    $monthNode.onclick = function(){toggleZoom(this)};

at the moment I cam controlling the zoom using this JS:

```
function toggleZoom(month) {

var zoomed = window.getComputedStyle(month).zIndex;
var m = document.getElementsByClassName("month");

for(var i = 0; i < m.length; i++)
    {
     m[i].style ='' ;
    }

if (zoomed != 2) {
    month.style = 'transform:scale(1.1,1.1); z-index:2';
    }
}
```

Is there a cleaner way (one line of code, maybe) to reset all of my month classes to un-zoomed without looping through all 12? Something like document.getElementsByClassName("month").style=""

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function to loop through your array in a single line without creating a `for` loop, like so: `m.map(function(mo){ mo.style = ''; });`

```js
function toggleZoom(month) {

  var zoomed = window.getComputedStyle(month).zIndex;
  var m = document.getElementsByClassName("month");

  m.map(function(mo){ mo.style = ''; });

  if (zoomed != 2) {
    month.style = 'transform:scale(1.1,1.1); z-index:2';
  }
}
```

Or, using [ES6's arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```js
function toggleZoom(month) {

  var zoomed = window.getComputedStyle(month).zIndex;
  var m = document.getElementsByClassName("month");

  m.map(mo => mo.style = '');

  if (zoomed != 2) {
    month.style = 'transform:scale(1.1,1.1); z-index:2';
  }
}
```

Comment: These are both nice. Never knew about map!
Are either of these 2 answers or my original approach more resource/memory etc efficient or preferred, or is it just style.

Comment: @user1561769 That depends on the usage of these methods. [You can review a benchmark here which seems to favour `for`](https://jsperf.com/map-vs-for-loop-performance/6) but note that for a simple calendar with 12 items to loop through, the difference should be insignificant.